# Two bodies not colliding in Farseer Physics 3.3.2

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

I am currently working on a game project using Farseer Physics for XNA.  Right now I have two classes extending the Body class that comes with Farseer. Below is my code for having them collide.

The below classes should be a little self-explanatory. Basically, I want the player to be able to collide with all of the tiles in the world.

```
    public Player(World gameWorld, GameWindow Window, int playernum, Texture2D sprite) : base(gameWorld)
    {
        //place the player in the center of the screen - this whole method can be changed
        Position = new Vector2(Window.ClientBounds.Width / 2, Window.ClientBounds.Height / 2);
        playerSprite = sprite;
        playerNum = (PlayerIndex)playernum;

        //Fixture stuff
        playerFixture = FixtureFactory.AttachRectangle(sprite.Width, sprite.Height, 1, new Vector2(), this);
        playerFixture.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat2;
        playerFixture.CollidesWith = Category.Cat1;
        playerFixture.OnCollision += playerOnCollision;
        //initialize the melee weapon
        //initialize the ranged weapon
    }

    public Tile(World gameWorld, Vector2 location, Game1 game, Vector2 offset) : base(gameWorld)
    {
        //Loading content in the constructor for simplicity's sake because the content manager is initialized by the time the stage is created
        health = 100;
        prevhealth = health;
        maxhealth = health;

        this.game = game;
        contentName = game.random.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? "Images/Tiles/MarbleTilesBreak" : "Images/Tiles/MarbleTiles1Break";
        tileTex = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(contentName + "0");
        //breakSound = game.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Tiles/FloorBreaking");
        location.X *= tileTex.Width;
        location.Y *= tileTex.Height;
        location += offset;
        Position = location;
        tileFixture = FixtureFactory.AttachRectangle(tileTex.Width, tileTex.Height, 1, new Vector2(), this);
        tileFixture.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat1;
        tileFixture.CollidesWith = Category.Cat2;
        tileFixture.OnCollision += _OnCollision;
    }
```

My _OnCollision looks like this:

```
    public bool _OnCollision(Fixture fix1, Fixture fix2, Contact con)
    {
        if (fix2.CollisionCategories == Category.Cat2)
        {
            health -= 10f;
        }
      return false;
    }
```

Yet when I run the code there is no sign of collision. When a tile is at 0 health, it should be deleted, but no tile is ever deleted.

Comment: Are you stepping the farseer world class?

Comment: Using world.Step(1) did resolve the collision problems. Now, however, the fixture is not moving.

Comment: Try Step((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds * 0.001f);

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that to move my sprite, I had to step the world like they mentioned in the comments, and then assign the sprite's position to the body's position, which stepping the world updated for me.

```
world.step(TIME_SPEED);
sprite.Position = body.Position;
```